# struct size 12, struct object align to 8, possible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to define a struct so that `sizeof(myStruct) = 12`, and `__alignof(myStruct) = 8`.

```
struct myStruct{
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
    int32_t c;
};
```

Is this possible?

Currently I have to do it manually as below:

```
__declspec(align(8)) myStruct str1; // Assume str1 start at 0x00
__declspec(align(8)) myStruct str2; // str2 address is 0x10
__declspec(align(8)) myStruct str3; // str3 address is 0x20
double abc;                         //  abc address is 0x2C
__declspec(align(8)) myStruct str4; // str4 address is 0x38
```

Comment: Don't assume that `int` is exactly 4 bytes long. Nothing requires it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of an object must be a multiple of its alignment requirement. 8 is not a factor of 12. Therefore no, you cannot have a type with size 12, and alignment of 8.

You can request for a stricter alignment than the sub objects of the class would require using the `alignas` specifier, and the size of the class will increase accordingly. Your example class would be padded to 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental requirement of C++ is that the size of an array `T[N]` is `N * sizeof(T)`, and that each array element is aligned correctly for `T`. This implied immediately that the alignment of a type must divide its size.